# General Solution to Nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

The functions $f(x) = \tanh(x/2)$ and $f(x) = \coth(x/2)$ satisfy the nonlinear differential equation:

$$-f'' + \textstyle\frac{1}{2}(f^2 - 1)f = 0$$

Is there any way I can find the more general solution to this differential equation knowing the example tanh and coth solutions?

Comment: I do not think that $f(x) = \tanh(x/2)$ or $f(x) = \coth(x/2)$ satisfy $-f'' + \textstyle\frac{1}{2}(f^2 + 1)f = 0$

Comment: The solution is given by $$\left\{\left\{y(x)\to -i \sqrt{\sqrt{1-4 c_1}+1} \text{sn}\left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\sqrt{1-4
   c_1} x^2-x^2+2 \sqrt{1-4 c_1} c_2 x-2 c_2 x+\sqrt{1-4 c_1}
   c_2{}^2-c_2{}^2}|\frac{\sqrt{1-4 c_1}+1}{1-\sqrt{1-4 c_1}}\right)\right\},\left\{y(x)\to
   i \sqrt{\sqrt{1-4 c_1}+1} \text{sn}\left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\sqrt{1-4 c_1} x^2-x^2+2
   \sqrt{1-4 c_1} c_2 x-2 c_2 x+\sqrt{1-4 c_1} c_2{}^2-c_2{}^2}|\frac{\sqrt{1-4
   c_1}+1}{1-\sqrt{1-4 c_1}}\right)\right\}\right\}$$

Comment: The correct version of the equation appears to be $-f''+\frac12(f^2-1)f=0$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes, you're right.  Semiclassical is correct too -- have made typo which I just fixed.

Comment: WolframAlpha does report the (awful) general solution ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-y%27%27%2B%28y%5E2-1%29y%2F2%3D0)). Whether that can be placed in more useful form remains to be seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### First integral

As usual with a kinetic equation in a potential field, multiply with $2f'$ and integrate
$$
-f'(x)^2+\frac14(f(x)^2-1)^2=C
$$

---

#### Reparametrization of the level curve

This has the general form $A^2-B^2=C$ and can thus be parametrized by hyperbolic functions.

- **Case $C=R^2>0$, $R\ne0$:** $f'(x)=R\sinh(g(x))$, $f(x)^2-1=2R\cosh(g(x))$, so that also $$
  f(x)f'(x)=  R\sinh(g(x))g'(x)= f'(x)g'(x).
  $$ 
  Consequently $g'(x)= f(x)$, so $$g''(x) = R\sinh(g(x)),$$ which has no simple solution, WA gives solutions in terms of the Jacobi amplitude function.

---

- **Case $C=-R^2<0$, $R\ne0$:** $f'(x)=R\cosh(g(x))$, $f(x)^2-1=2R\sinh(g(x))$, again $g'(x)=f(x)$, $$g''(x)=R\cosh(g(x))$$ follows. Again WA gives solutions in terms of the Jacobi amplitude function.

---

- **Case $C=0$:** Now $f'(x)=\pm\frac12(f(x)^2-1)$. This results in the two functions that were the point of departure for this question, the form
  $$
  f(x)=\pm \frac{e^x-K}{e^x+K}
  $$
  contains all the variants.